# sketchtool CLI with fish shell

Tags: config, fish

I tried for a while to get the fish shell equivalent for the sketch cli initialization commands. Can anyone help?

For fish it the first line seems to work if you remove the '$' character. Second line for the argument passing I've tried removing the $, the quotes, & several different formats. Couldn't find documentation for argument passing initialization in fish.

```
#!/bin/sh

SKETCH=$(mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == 'com.bohemiancoding.sketch3' | head -n 1)

# pass on all given arguments
"$SKETCH/Contents/Resources/sketchtool/bin/sketchtool" "$@"
```

reference: https://developer.sketch.com/cli/

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
set SKETCH (mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == 'com.bohemiancoding.sketch3' | head -n 1)

$SKETCH/Contents/Resources/sketchtool/bin/sketchtool $argv
```

Comment: ~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 21): Variables may not be used as commands. In fish, please define a function or use 'eval $SKETCH/Contents/Resources/sketchtool/bin/sketchtool'.
$SKETCH/Contents/Resources/sketchtool/bin/sketchtool $argv
^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
 called during startup

Comment: What does `fish --version` show? This ought to work in fish 3.0 or later.

Comment: It showed 2.7, and I upgraded with brew upgrade fish. Thanks!! When I start the shell now with this in the config, I get a ton of output, starting with: `Usage: sketchtool <command> [<args>]`, any idea what this might be about? This means its working but definitely tried to execute a command without args or something.